# SSRS enterprise edition installation

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am working on installing SSRS on my machine, and I do not know anything about SSRS.
While I went ahead with downloading the exe, it asked me if I want :
ISO
CAB
Microsoft azure

Could anyone help me with what this means. And any help on the installation would help as well.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Install it from Microsoft website (Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843